# Controles distintos en el contenido de cada nodo del TreeView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me encuentro creando este formulario de Búsqueda que básicamente contiene un TreeView con varios nodos como os muestro en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Muestra de la interfaz de búsqueda de mi app]

El objetivo es que al pulsar en cada nodo aparezcan unos controles distintos en el panel de la derecha, es decir, como si fuesen páginas individuales con sus propios controles, no sé si me explico.

Por ejemplo, en Nombre quiero ese TextBox y algún CheckBox para que el usuario elija si quiere sensibilidad a mayus/minus o no. Pero en Categoría quiero una lista o múltiples CheckBox para seleccionar la categoría de contactos que desea filtrar en la lista, por ej. personal, familiar, trabajo, etc.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creaste los nodos del treeview podrias asignar la propiedad `Tag` con la instancia del user control que debe usarse en el panel de la derecha

entonces en el evento de seleccion del nodo usarias

```
private void TreeView1_BeforeSelect(Object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e) {

    UserControl uc = e.Node.Tag as UserControl;
    Panel1.Controls.Add(uc);

}
```

[TreeNode.Tag Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

asignando el Tag puede poner info contextual al dato del nodo para conocer que user control debes mostrar ne cada caso. Cuando sea el nodo del Nombre asignaras el user control que muestre el textbox

Comment: Creo que lo he entendido, pero en el caso de que en el panel derecho hubieran tantos controles como en esta imagen: https://i.imgur.com/d6kM6We.png esa es la única forma de hacerlo? No sería demasiado trabajo?

Comment: Entiendo que deberias definir un user control con el diseño que aplica para ese nodo. Seran tantos diseños distintos  como diferentes nodos tengas en el treeview